# Styles not supporting Geometry Drawing

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to implement a vector geometry drawing in my UserControl.

The problem I encountered, is that whenever i set the Image property of the UserControl to my geometry drawing, everything goes fine.
But, when I don't set it directly, but through the styles and triggers, it doesn't work.

It's probably worth noting, that the styles approach that doesn't work here, actually works if we are using an Image from a file (a bitmap based one).

Example **(this DOES work)**:

```
 <userControls:ImageButton Image="{StaticResource phoneIconBlue}" Text="Notatka" Width="200" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Example **(this DOESN'T work)**:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<userControls:ImageButton Style="{StaticResource phoneImageButtonUCStyle}" Text="Telefon" Width="200" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="phoneImageButtonUCStyle" TargetType="ImageButtonUC:ImageButton">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Image" Value="{StaticResource phoneIconBlue}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Image" Value="{StaticResource phoneIconBlue}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This is most likely irrelevant, but here is the geometry that I'm using:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="phoneIconBlue">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red" Geometry="M577.83,456.128c1.225,9.385-1.635,17.545-8.568,24.48l-81.396,80.781
        c-3.672,4.08-8.465,7.551-14.381,10.404c-5.916,2.857-11.729,4.693-17.439,5.508c-0.408,0-1.635,0.105-3.676,0.309
        c-2.037,0.203-4.689,0.307-7.953,0.307c-7.754,0-20.301-1.326-37.641-3.979s-38.555-9.182-63.645-19.584
        c-25.096-10.404-53.553-26.012-85.376-46.818c-31.823-20.805-65.688-49.367-101.592-85.68
        c-28.56-28.152-52.224-55.08-70.992-80.783c-18.768-25.705-33.864-49.471-45.288-71.299
        c-11.425-21.828-19.993-41.616-25.705-59.364S4.59,177.362,2.55,164.51s-2.856-22.95-2.448-30.294
        c0.408-7.344,0.612-11.424,0.612-12.24c0.816-5.712,2.652-11.526,5.508-17.442s6.324-10.71,10.404-14.382L98.022,8.756
        c5.712-5.712,12.24-8.568,19.584-8.568c5.304,0,9.996,1.53,14.076,4.59s7.548,6.834,10.404,11.322l65.484,124.236
        c3.672,6.528,4.692,13.668,3.06,21.42c-1.632,7.752-5.1,14.28-10.404,19.584l-29.988,29.988c-0.816,0.816-1.53,2.142-2.142,3.978
        s-0.918,3.366-0.918,4.59c1.632,8.568,5.304,18.36,11.016,29.376c4.896,9.792,12.444,21.726,22.644,35.802
        s24.684,30.293,43.452,48.653c18.36,18.77,34.68,33.354,48.96,43.76c14.277,10.4,26.215,18.053,35.803,22.949
        c9.588,4.896,16.932,7.854,22.031,8.871l7.648,1.531c0.816,0,2.145-0.307,3.979-0.918c1.836-0.613,3.162-1.326,3.979-2.143
        l34.883-35.496c7.348-6.527,15.912-9.791,25.705-9.791c6.938,0,12.443,1.223,16.523,3.672h0.611l118.115,69.768
        C571.098,441.238,576.197,447.968,577.83,456.128z">
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
```

Where the image property of the userControl is simply a dependency property set to the image.

At first, I thought It may have something to do with the layout, but that was debunked.

I had also eliminated the possibility, that It may be caused by how I designed my userControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed.

It seems that app.xaml isn't reordered by the compiler as most things in C# are, 
and simply putting the geometry definition above the Style solved the problem.